# Looking for photo gallery with support for normal view without lightbox and full screen view and caption support

Tags: open-source, javascript, image-viewer, bootstrap

Despite spending several days I cannot find an open source photo gallery that has following:

1. Full screen support but starts as normal window view (not lightbox view meaning not taking the full viewport of the browser like a modal), when user clicks on full screen view icon, then it goes full screen taking the whole screen of device. Photoswipe has this issue -- it starts as lightbox which can go full screen by clicking the icon.
2. Responsive text captioning. On large screen captions are bigger and on phones it becomes small. Bootstrap 4 Carousal has this issue, it simply hides caption on phones instead of making it responsive - quite unexpected from bootstrap team. Also it does not support full screen
3. Ideally it should be based off Bootstrap 4 but at least it should work with Bootstrap 4.

I also tried blueimp photo gallery which according to docs has full screen support but cannot find any demo or example code to show full screen. Also it does not support responsive captioning.